# .ics Calendar File always appears as busy in Outlook for Mac

Tags: outlook, icalendar, outlook-for-mac

I am attempting to send out .ics calendar event files which can be downloaded by users and saved to their Outlook calendars. The calendar event needs to appear as “Free” in Outlook. Below is a sample of the .ics event currently being sent out:

> `BEGIN:VCALENDAR
>      VERSION:2.0
>      PRODID:http://company.ical.cls
>      BEGIN:VEVENT
>      DTSTART:20180425
>      SUMMARY:PTO for Babcock, Michael (22.5hrs)
>      DTEND:20180428
>      FREEBUSY:FREE
>      END:VEVENT
>      END:VCALENDAR`

When an Outlook for Windows user downloads the above file and opens it in their Outlook calendar, the event appears correctly as Free time.

When an Outlook for Mac user downloads the above file it creates a new email with the .ics file attached. 
To try to correct the problem for Mac users, I edited the FREEBUSY keyword several times to appear as:

- `FBTYPE:FREE:20180425T000000Z/20180428T000000Z`
- `FBTYPE:20180426T000000Z/20180429T000000Z`
- `FREEBUSY;FBTYPE=FREE:20180416T133000Z/20180429T170000Z`

Outlook for Mac users could download the file with one of those new FreeBusy keywords and open it in their calendar, but it always appears as Busy. The strange thing is, if they open the file with the modified keyword on a Windows computer first, then the appointment appears as free on both Windows and Mac Outlook.

Has anyone found a FreeBusy keyword that allows Outlook for Mac users to see .ics calendar appointments as Free?

Comment: https://icalendar.org/iCalendar-RFC-5545/3-2-9-free-busy-time-type.html has examples of how to specify, and a further breakdown of the format

Answer (score 1):

FREEBUSY is for requesting/responding/publishing availability windows.

To make the event appear in the calendar with the Free/Busy flag set to Free, use `TRANSP:TRANSPARENT` and `X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:FREE`

For example:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
  VERSION:2.0
  PRODID:http://company.ical.cls
  BEGIN:VEVENT
  DTSTART:20180425
  SUMMARY:PTO for Babcock, Michael (22.5hrs)
  DTEND:20180428
  TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
  X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:FREE
  END:VEVENT
  END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'Freebusy' component is VFREEBUSY, not VEVENT.  Please see the RFC5545 specification. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.6.4

VFREEBUSY cannot be nested under VEVENT.  Also it does NOT say that FREEBUSY **property** can be used in VEVENT.   The spec at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.2.6  says:

> FREEBUSY..... Conformance:  The property can be specified in a
> "VFREEBUSY" calendar
> component.

...

> The following is an example of a "VFREEBUSY" calendar component
> used to publish busy time information:
>
> ```
>    BEGIN:VFREEBUSY
>    UID:19970901T115957Z-76A912@example.com
>    DTSTAMP:19970901T120000Z
>    ORGANIZER:jsmith@example.com
>    DTSTART:19980313T141711Z
>    DTEND:19980410T141711Z
>    FREEBUSY:19980314T233000Z/19980315T003000Z
>    FREEBUSY:19980316T153000Z/19980316T163000Z
>    FREEBUSY:19980318T030000Z/19980318T040000Z
>    URL:http://www.example.com/calendar/busytime/jsmith.ifb
>    END:VFREEBUSY
> ```